# Complexity of a query in the Google datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an Android app where users will be able to send private messages to each other. (for instance: A sends a message to B and C and the three of them may comment that message)

I use google app engine and the google datastore with Java. (framework Objectify)
I have created a `Member` entity and a `Message` entity which contains a `ArrayList<String>` field, representing the recipients'ids list. (that is to say the key field of the `Member` entity)

In order for a user to get all the messages where he is one of the recipients, I was planning on loading each `Message` entity on the datastore and then select them by checking if the `ArrayList<String>` field contains the user's id. However, considering there may be hundred of thousands messages stored, I was wondering if that is even possible and if that wouldn't take too much time?

Comment: Does `ofy().load().type(Message.class).filter('recipient =', myMemberId)` not do what you want?  How many recipients `Member`s will a `Message` realistically have?

Comment: I think this should do the work, thank you. I guess on average a `Message` will have a recipients list of 8 Members'id. Do you still believe your query will be convenient?

Answer (score 1):

The time to fetch results from the datastore only relates to the number of Entities retrieved, not to the total number of Entities stored because every query MUST use an index. That's exactly what makes the datastore so scalable.

You will have to limit the number of messages retrieved per call and use a [Cursor](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Cursor_Example) to fetch the next batch. You can send the cursor over to the Android client by converting it to a [websafe string](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/Cursor#toWebSafeString()), so the client can indicate the starting point for the next request.

Comment: In fact a Member won't have that much Messages which are addressed to him. Actually he might not have more than 50 messages since I plan to delete them every week or so. The only size-problem I will probably cope with is the total number of Messages in the datastore, which may be quite big. I'm not sure about what you mean by "every query must use an index", but will the query suggested by tx802 (ofy().load().type(Message.class).filter('recipient =', myMemberId) and adding @Index to fhe List field fit that requirement?

Comment: Yes, the List of member IDs (or Keys) would need an `@Index` annotation to be used in a query like this.

Comment: @tx802 actually your query returns an empty Collection. Are you sure this is not something like `ofy().load().type(Message.class).filter('recipient contains', myMemberId)` ?

Comment: @Gannicus the query from tx802 is correct, but did you add Index annotation on the recipients BEFORE saving the data. Data already present will not get indexed unless re-saved.

Comment: @koma yes I already met that issue before so I did. Actually I'm pretty sure that request won't work, considering for instance that SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595327/objectify-query-filters-like-name-contains

Comment: @Gannicus the query in the referenced post talks about a String containing a character, which won't work. Butofy().load().type(Message.class).filter('recipient =', myMemberId) will work ('=' NOT contains) where Message holds a List of recipients. myMemberId must be an EXACT match in the List.

Comment: @koma unfortunately I can assure you it won't return anything but an empty Collection. I even performed that test on a very simple app just to be sure I didn't do something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: if you have Entity(Message) { msg : "hello world", recipients = [ 1,2,5,7,8] } then the query ``ofy().load().type(Message.class).filter('recipients=', 5)`` will return you given message.